# Trouble setting directory permissions

Tags: apache

I'm struggling to find the right combination for setting permissions on a directory such that the group owner can read, write, and execute and everyone else has no permissions (i.e., can't see or access).

What's the right combination?

My current permissions are as follows:

`drwxrwx--- 4 apache ec2andapache 4096 Aug 18 17:40 /var/www/html/import`

Answer (score 0):

That would just be 070. But if 'apache' was a member of 'ec2andapache' then that users access would be denied.  If that's not what you expect, 770 is what you want.

Comment: I just did this, but I can still access this folder directory via my browser: `sudo chmod -R 770 /var/www/html/import/token`